# How to setup a per-user private space

Tags: joomla

I need to configure Joomla site where a user can

1. Register - This will register the user and create his/her own private area
2. Log In to his/her private area
3. Create content (articles, upload files and documents etc) in his private area
4. Share specific content with other individual users if he so chooses

So far, I haven't been able to find a Joomla plugin/extension/component which would allow me to setup a per-user private space. Is there any known plugin for this? Any other suggestions would be much appreciated.

I have joomla 3.3 currently.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a component called [BS Myjspace](http://extensions.joomla.org/profile/extension/authoring-a-content/blog/bs-myjspace), it seems to be able to do exactly what you're asking for, except maybe #4 - *Share specific content with other individual users if he so chooses*, but there might be a plugin for this too.

> **Key features:**
>    * Registered user can create a (or several) personal page(s) with a WYSIWYG page editor, name and rename page
>    * Upload images, medias from editor (optional administrator choices with quotas parameters) to avoid external storage website to use
>   * Upload files from user admin page to avoid external storage website to use
>   * Automatic resizing (optional) for images (jpg, png, gif)
>   * Choose who can see the page: public, registers users or none
>   * Search for pages name, content... Result displayed as list or nice tab from the component and multilingual.
>   * A lot of user information tags: create date, update date, last access date, hits, files list ...
>   * Allow Joomla plugins usage. Users can use pictures or media plugin to create a gallery with user page files uploaded
>   * Numerous features for administrator with friendly interface to manage a lot of pages
>   * Ability to use Pagebreak and index; with the plg_pagebreakmyjspace
>   * Ability to add external image link or url using bbcode format
>   * Ability to use publishing dates (start and finish)
>   * Ability or not to use url redirection
>   * Ability to personalize top page and bottom page (for admin) or in the page (for users) with reserved words
>   * Ability to use the included Lytebox effect in the page, without any other add
>   * Languages: fr-FR, en-GB...
>   * Several others options and features  <sup>1</sup>

And best of all, it's free!

<sup>1</sup>http://extensions.joomla.org/profile/extension/authoring-a-content/blog/bs-myjspace

Comment: Thanks @johanpw. This does looks like a component that would fit my most needs. I will surely try this.